# Task.Delay stops the continuous looped program after a day or two

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task

I have a .NET webAPI in which I keep running Task method in a loop continuously (until the app is running).

I am using a `await Task.Delay(120000)` before calling next LoopMethod task.
The API runs continuously well for 1 or 2 days and then stops at a point where last log file statement says, `log.Debug("Before Task Delay..")`;

It means at some point Task `await Task.Delay(120000);` never completes.

Is there something I am missing?

Here is a sample snippet format i am using

I am using a recursion because next LoopMethod parameter depends on the return value of previous LoopMethod.

```
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> LoopMethod(string token) 
{
    var responseHttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unused;

   string NextToken =  await DoSomething();

    log.Debug("Before Task Delay..");
    await Task.Delay(120000);
    log.Debug("After Task Delay..");

    await LoopMethod(NextToken); 

    return responseHttpStatusCode;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this code is going the way of the Titanic, its a recursive never ending method , it stops because it probably runs out of stack and hits the  `StackOverflowException` iceberg

Comment: If you really need to do this, put it in a `while(true)` with at least some way for it to exit

Comment: @TheGeneral Ahh, good eye. I hadn't seen the recursion. That's most likely the problem yes

Comment: The looping stops at  await Task.Delay(120000); after around between 20 to 30 hours every time. So every time it stops, I restart the api Call manually again. If IIS is recycling the api how can i avoid it recycling. I am sleeping for 2 minutes because I am consuming another webservice in my API to which I am giving a call every 2 minutes. Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: You could use a non-recursive loop for a quick fix. But the better option is to refactor to use a timer and get rid of the loop completely.

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks I will try it!

Comment: I am using a recursion because next LoopMethod parameter depends on the return value of previous LoopMethod.

Comment: That doesn't require recursion. There are many loops which change a state variable between iterations, most notably the `for` loop...

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure whether this is being called form your webserver, or your client code. if its the webserver, you shouldn't be running longing running tasks like this. The *ApplicationPool* will recycle and tear it down eventually.

However my spidey senses tells me this is client side and you are just running out of stack, which in-turn is causing a `StackOverflowException`

> The most common cause of stack overflow is excessively deep or
>   infinite recursion, in which a function calls itself so many times
>   that the space needed to store the variables and information
>   associated with each call is more than can fit on the stack.

If you really need to do this consider just a while loop

```
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> LoopMethod() 
{

    while(true)
    {
       ...

       await Task.Delay(120000);

       if(condition)
          //break or return

       ...
      }
}
```

Or as *John Wu* suggests, just use a timer with a state

if this IS a webserver, consider using a service to poll, which is designed to persist and not recycle

**Updated from comments**

[From Kevin Gosse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869621/kevin-gosse)

> While I agree there's no point in using recursion here, note that
>   there's no actual recursion here. Because of async/await and the fact
>   that Task.Delay will never complete synchronously, each continuation
>   has its own call stack and the stack usage does not actually grow. You
>   can convince yourself by logging the value of Environment.StackTrace
>   at the beginning of the method. That said, you still create tasks at
>   each iteration, so you'll run out of memory at some point

Comment: I am using a recursion because next LoopMethod parameter depends on the return value of previous LoopMethod.

Comment: @NikhilShinde yes thats fine, however if this method runs too many times it will crash your app. If you need that parameter just use a local variable with a loop, or field with a timer. If this is a webservice you a doing this, you shouldn't be using long running tasks like that. There is plenty of documentation on the net about the whys

Comment: While I agree there's no point in using recursion here, note that there's no *actual* recursion here. Because of async/await and the fact that `Task.Delay` will never complete synchronously, each continuation has its own call stack and the stack usage does not actually grow. You can convince yourself by logging the value of `Environment.StackTrace` at the beginning of the method. That said, you still create tasks at each iteration, so you'll run out of memory at some point

Comment: @TheGeneral So this is a webserver and I am not using any client application to consume this service. I just cheeked the Evnt Logs of IIS Web Server. It shows up the event logs at the time webservice stopped. Evnt Log 1.Event ID 5013 — IIS Application Pool Availability - "A process serving application pool XYZ exceeded time limits during shut down." and Event Log 2 at the same time 2. Event ID 5138— IIS Protocol Adapter Availability : "A worker process serving application pool failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.The data field contains the error number.".